# Setting certain column value of each row in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have a 150 X 4 matrix called Z.

I do some operation to this and what I have left is Z again.

```
[o p] = min(Z, [], 2);
```

Gives me the column number for each row.

I need to set that particular column for each row to 1 and rest to zero.

I thought of doing this but it didn't work out.

```
K = zeros(size(Z));
K(:, p) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go through [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
K = full( sparse( 1:size(Z,1), p.', 1, size(Z,1), size(Z,2) ) );
```

Alternatively, you can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
K = zeros( size(Z) );
K( sub2ind( size(K), 1:size(K,1), p.' ) ) = 1;
```

If you are certain there is only one maximal element in each row you can

```
K = bsxfun( @eq, Z, o );
```

Comment: Think it has to be `[1:size(K,1)]'` in `sub2ind` solution

Comment: Right, either of that.

Answer (score 1):

One approach -

```
K = zeros(size(Z))
K((p-1)*size(Z,1)+[1:size(Z,1)]')=1
```

Comment: I got a `bsxfun` approach ;)

Comment: This is why I prefer using `sub2ind` rather than do it myself... easier to debug and to read

Comment: You are correct, but I don't think that indexing a 150x4 matrix raises any performance issues...